# Using a UNION in nested queries with SUM calculations

Tags: sql

i want to show sum of this query as only one cell but here the result shows as a column like this Total Sum

```
  500
  1000
```

but i want to show the sum of this records (1500)

this is my query :

```
select sum(MAL_TASWYAHESAB.MADINMONY) as'Total Sum' from MAL_TASWYAHESAB  
union 
select sum(MAL_AMRSARF_OHAD.MONY) as'Total Sum' from MAL_AMRSARF_OHAD
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
select (select sum(MAL_TASWYAHESAB.MADINMONY) from MAL_TASWYAHESAB)
+
(select sum(MAL_AMRSARF_OHAD.MONY) from MAL_AMRSARF_OHAD) as 'Total Sum'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(TotalSum) AS Total
FROM
(
    select MAL_TASWYAHESAB.MADINMONY as 'TotalSum' from MAL_TASWYAHESAB  
    union 
    select MAL_AMRSARF_OHAD.MONY                   from MAL_AMRSARF_OHAD
) AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(MADINMONY) as'Total Sum'
from (
    select MAL_TASWYAHESAB.MADINMONY
    from MAL_TASWYAHESAB
    union MAL_AMRSARF_OHAD.MONY
    from MAL_AMRSARF_OHAD
) AS X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(MADINMONY) as'Total Sum'
FROM (
    SELECT MAL_TASWYAHESAB.MADINMONY
    FROM MAL_TASWYAHESAB
    UNION MAL_AMRSARF_OHAD.MONY
    FROM MAL_AMRSARF_OHAD
) AS a;
```